# Greasemonkey/Tempermonkey script for Deviantart

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a script to add a button on DA top bar, that link to the notes page, since DA removed the one they had

So far I can manage to add a button, but I can't make it use DA icons and the button goes at the bottom of the page instead of the top bar

I found how to make the button work, but I can't figure out how to get DA css and use it to change my button  (I can do the css myself, if I could just know how to inject it in there?)

Anyone could help me please?

```js
    // ==UserScript==
// @name         DA notes button
// @namespace
// @version      0.1
// @description
// @author
// @match        https://www.deviantart.com/
// @grant        none

var input=document.createElement("input");
input.type="button";
input.value="Notes";
input.onclick = OpenNotes;
document.body.appendChild(input);



function OpenNotes()
{
    window.location = "https://www.deviantart.com/notifications/notes"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have rewriten some stuff, you can test it out and see if it works for you.

I used  `Object.assign(button.style, cssObj);`  to add styling from your style object and i added an event listener to the button to add action to click event..

```
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  addButton("Notes button");
});

function addButton(text, onclick, cssObj) {
  cssObj = cssObj || {
    position: "fixed",
    top: "15%",
    right: "4%",
    "z-index": 3,
    fontWeight: "600",
    fontSize: "14px",
    backgroundColor: "#00cccc",
    color: "white",
    border: "none",
    padding: "10px 20px"
  };

  let button = document.createElement("button");
  Object.assign(button.style, cssObj);

  button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    window.location.href = "http://www.w3schools.com";
    return false;
  });

  button.innerHTML = text;

  document.body.appendChild(button);
}
```

Comment: since you have changed your question this code is an answer to the previus code you added, but it solwes the new question so i am posting it anyway..

Comment: Yes this is perfect! And I'll experiment with the css and see what I got wrong, because your code is just so much more compact than the mess I had XD